# Does anyone has any success with distribute in-house apps in internal web server?

Tags: ios9, in-house-distribution

Our company used to be able to distribute in-house apps on a simple internal web server.
However since Apple update the iOS to version 9, since then it no longer work anymore.

Once a user clicked on "Install" confirmation after that the alert pop up with,
Title "Unable to Download App"
Message: "Your App" could not be downloaded at this time.

I don't know what change that I need to do to make distribute in-house working again.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out the problem. In new iOS 9, you need to make sure that your "Bundle Identifier" must match with your ipa file and plist.
Finally, I got it working.